# This code will not output anything to the webpage?

Tags: javascript

I want to complete this assignment for class by outputting the code and it's not working. I've tried putting random print statements throughout my code to see what part of the code is failing but still, nothing showed up.

```js
var results1;
var results2;
var results3;
var results4;
var results5;
var results6;
var results7;
var results8;

// Calculations
results1 = (7 > 5);
results2 = (5 < 5);
results3 = ("a" < "b"); 
results4 = (100 <= 99); 
results5 = ("100" !== 100); 
results6 = (0 > 10);
results7 = ("100" > "99"); 
results8 = ("A" == 92); 

// Output
document.write("1. (7 > 5)    --> " + results1 + "\n" );
document.write("2. (5 < 5)    --> " + results2 + "\n" );
document.write("3. ("a" < "b")    --> " + results3 + "\n" );
document.write("4. (100 <= 99)    --> " + results4 + "\n" );
document.write("5. ("100" !== 100)    --> " + results5 + "\n" );
document.write "6. (0 > 10)    --> " + results6 + "\n" );
document.write("7. ("100" > "99")    --> " + results7 + "\n" );
document.write("8. ("A" === 92)    --> " + results8 + "\n" );
```

Comment: I would avoid `document.write`. There is really no reason to use it. Manipulate the DOM instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have quotation marks that aren't escaped properly. Change your output part to this:

```
document.write("1. (7 > 5)    --> " + results1 + "<br/>" );
document.write("2. (5 < 5)    --> " + results2 + "<br/>" );
document.write("3. (\"a\" < \"b\")    --> " + results3 + "<br/>" ); // Added "\" 
document.write("4. (100 <= 99)    --> " + results4 + "<br/>" );
document.write("5. (\"100\" !== 100)    --> " + results5 + "<br/>" ); // Added "\" 
document.write("6. (0 > 10)    --> " + results6 + "<br/>" ); // Added "(" 
document.write("7. (\"100\" > \"99\")    --> " + results7 + "<br/>" ); // Added "\" 
document.write("8. (\"A\" === 92)    --> " + results8 + "<br/>" ); // Added "\"
```